# Excel ignoring rowspawn/colspawn when reading html

Tags: html, excel

In our program we export data to Excel via opening html that we made, it can contain a lot of cells merged via rowspan/colspan and it seems like at some point Excel just start to ignore them, while in browser everything is okay.

For this question I made a simple table, consisting of 3 rows and just copy and pasted it until table had like 10k rows.

That's how it looks in browser:

[image: That's how it looks in browser:]

And that's when it gets broken in excel:

[image: And that's when it gets broken in excel:]

Any way to fix it without giving up on html cell merging? Code for 3 repeated rows of table below:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">rows2</td>
    <td colspan="10" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols10</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="4" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">rows2 cols4</td>
    <td colspan="15" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols15</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="5" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">rows2 cols5</td>
    <td colspan="15" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols5</td>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols5</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols3</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols3</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols3</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols3</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols3</td>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols5</td>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols5</td>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">cols5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="50" align="center" style="border: thin solid black">empty</td>
</tr>
</table>
```